# JSP - Date objects from drop down list

Tags: java, class, jsp, object

So I currently have a registration.html page that holds two dates in a drop down list.

```
    <td>Preferred Date:</td>
    <td><select name="datePreferred">
            <option value="dateOne">08/18/2012</option>
            <option value="dateTwo">08/25/2012</option>
    </select>
    </td>
```

For my JSP page I have the following

```
    <%
    String dPreferred = request.getParameter("datePreferred");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
    Date dateObj = dateFormat.parse(dPreferred);
    %>
```

However I seem to be getting "Cannot find symbol - symbol: class Date - location: class SimplifiedJSPServlet

What I am trying to do is create and store a date object that can be written to a text file and also displayed on a verification page.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: If you submit a form with this select you will get the strings `dateOne` or `dateTwo` as a the `datePreferred` parameter. If you try to parse that, it will throw a `ParseException`.

Comment: So, I assume I should remove the value, and just have the date?

Comment: No, put the string you want to parse in the value and have whatever description you want to have for the option inside the `<option>` tag. It could be the same as the value. Browsers usually submit the text of the option as the value, if you don't specify a value, but I would avoid that and always set a value. If you make an international webpage, it can also be useful to put the date in a parseable format into the value and in a different format into the text like `<option value="08/18/2012">Aug 18, 2012</option>` and then have different texts depending on the language of the visitor.

Comment: Ok, thats really good to know. (it would be nice at one point to be working on an international page :)). Thank you for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you imported Date in your JSP?:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
```